# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method play(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined

Tags: java, android

I created a program in which I added a video and 3 buttons. When I run on the phone, the program crashes.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method play(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'video_play'
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:436)
That's my code

```
 VideoView videoPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        videoPlayer =  (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        String uripath="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.peds;
        Uri myVideoUri= Uri.parse(uripath);
        videoPlayer.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);
    }
    public void play(View view){
        videoPlayer.start();
    }
    public void pause(View view){
        videoPlayer.pause();
    }
    public void stop(View view){
        videoPlayer.stopPlayback();
        videoPlayer.resume();
    }
```

And here XML

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/video_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Play"
        android:fontFamily="@font/kras"
        android:textColor="#C62828"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="4.4"
        android:shadowDy="2.4"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/video_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-214dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/video_play"
        android:onClick="pause"
        android:text="Pause"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/video_stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-324dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/video_play"
        android:onClick="stop"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:textSize="19sp"/>
```

Comment: Your method names are different in Java and XML

Answer (score 0):

Add to our play button in xml:

```
android:onClick="play"
```

Add to your pause button in xml

```
android:onClick="pause"
```

Add to your stop button in xml

```
android:onClick="stop"
```

**update**

look do what i said above, and find the buttons by ID:

```
private Button playButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private Button stopButton;


videoPlayer =  (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
//add these here
playButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_play);
pauseButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_pause);
stopButton =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.video_stop);
...
...
```

Comment: Before that, I entered the same name. I just changed that.
But before that, the result did not change.

Comment: Same result.
Also an error when clicking on the button